# Is 2^n + 1 = k^2 only valid when n = k = 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve this equation

$$
2^n + 1 = k^2
$$
but I found only one solution where 
$$
n=k=3
$$
Is there are any other solutions and how to prove if there is no more?

Comment: For $n$ even, there is no solution, because $2^n+1\equiv 1+1=2\not\equiv k^2\bmod 3$.

Comment: $2^n + 1 = k^2 \implies 2^n =k^2-1=(k+1)(k-1)\implies$ that $k+1$ and $k-1$ are both powers of $2$.

Comment: So we have $k-1=2^m$ and $k+1 = 2^w$.  But $2^w - 2^m = (k+1)-(k-1)=2$.  Is $2^w-2^m = 2$  possible? If so... when?

Comment: @fleablood please put your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Can't.  Your questions been closed.  And as pointed out it's already been answered.